# How to dynamically create tablelayout with an ImageView and TextView in each cell in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I am new in android, I manually created a tablelayout with 5 rows and 10 columns each in my xml. I managed to combine an imageview and textview in every cell using linearlayout. but my codes are to long and when running the program my eclipse crashes.

I saw some codes regarding creating tablelayout with imageview in each cell dynamically but I can't find something about combining imageview and textview in each cell. please help...

here is a part of my xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">



<TableLayout 
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:shrinkColumns="*"
    android:stretchColumns="*" 
    >

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"

 >

  <LinearLayout 
      android:id="@+id/l1"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:background="@android:drawable/list_selector_background">  



  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/s1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:src="@drawable/chair" />



   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/t1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="001" />

   </LinearLayout>


</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
<LinearLAyout>
```

I want it to be something like this where i can click on every cell, so I think listview can't solve my problem. I don't know also much if it can support my problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your rows seems to be identical. You should use [Listview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) with custom Adapter having imageview and textview in each row.

References:
[Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)
[Some More](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429)

Update:

Try using [GridView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html)

Comment: hi PravinCG, thanks for the reply. i edited my question to avoid confusion. i think listview can't solve my problem. i dont know much about listview so i dont know also if it is appropriate for my problem.